# How to add several class types inside a function while doing web scraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to collect several values from a website using an R function and the code I have is the following:

```
automatic = function(ETF) {
  ETF = read_html(paste0('https://www.justetf.com/de-en/etf-profile.html?query=',ETF,'&groupField=index&from=search&isin=',ETF,'#overview'))
  ETF = ETF %>%
        general_info = ETF%>%html_nodes(".val") %>% html_text()
        name_ETF = ETF%>%html_nodes(".h1") %>% html_text()
  return(ETF)
```

}

If I simply use the class ".val" the function works and I can retrieve and save the data to a data.frame using sapply, however, how can I do the same while using both classes (.val and .h1)?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

This is the code I've been using to get the information from .val, but I now want to add the .h1 class

```
automatic = function(ETF) {
  ETF = read_html(paste0('https://www.justetf.com/de-en/etf-profile.html?query=',ETF,'&groupField=index&from=search&isin=',ETF,'#overview'))
  ETF = ETF %>%
        html_nodes(".val") %>% html_text()
  return(ETF)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
> automatic = function(ETF) {
  ETF = read_html(paste0('https://www.justetf.com/de-en/etf-profile.html?query=',ETF,'&groupField=index&from=search&isin=',ETF,'#overview'))
  ETF = ETF %>%
        html_nodes(".h1, .val") %>% html_text()
  return(ETF)
```

}

Just simply pass the classes as html_nodes(".h1, .val, .etc")